# Damage to Arboerivities

Tags: trees

I have flat cedars/Arborivitaes in front of my house planted 5’ above the road and 5 ft back from the road stand 30’ h.  Recently the town redid our blacktop road by heating and relaying the top layer, in doing so they severly burnt the entire side of the trees.  Will they grow back?
I tried to post pictures but your site says too large.  Is there another way I send pictures?

Comment: Barbara, if your on Windows type paint into the search bar near the bottom left of your screen. This application allows you to resize photo's. It is simple, click File then Open and navigate to the picture. There is a resize tool click it and it will allow you to decrease the size of your photo. Select the size you want and click file and save. Then try to upload the image again.

Comment: Please send pictures ASAP.  Takes lots of them.  There is a center line in your road.  There is also a corridor, a stated distance from this Center Line  a right of way easement that the city can do what ever they want.  But not always.  If they didn't post their project, for instance, properly?  Your tree will probably live but doubtfully ever be symmetrical again.

Answer (score 2):

Arborvitae can be pruned quite hard and will come back. In my area deer love the cedars and chew them to death. If the trees possibly can they will spring back to life.

It sounds like you have a hedge which was scorched by road works. Resurfacing blacktop requires large amounts of heat focused downwards, but inevitably some escapes sideways. It's the responsibility of the contractor performing the work to take every precaution to minimize this sideways escape of heat. There is only so much he can do, but at least he has to make sure guards are in place if available.

Singeing nearby growth is a risk that is well known to both contractor and the town works department. Their responsibility is to cause minimum damage, your responsibility is to ensure that the hedge is well inside your property markers and has been trimmed back so that all growth is/was over your property.

First phone call goes to the local works department. "Would you kindly send someone to look at damage to my hedge?" Second call goes to a local landscape contractor (not a lawn specialist) "Could you come look at some damage to a hedge in need of repair and give me a quote?"

Let the works department know what the quote says. Give them the choice of paying for it or having their own crews do an equivalent job. But only if your side of the bargain is right, that is, that the hedge is fully on your side of your lot line. Good luck.

Comment: Excellent advice, Colin!  You know these 'politics'!